# Switching between formpages (tabs) of SWT FormEditor

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

I am working on a Plugin project in which we are using SWT `FormEditor` with different `FormPage`s. The first FormPage tab will act as a summary page, from where we need to navigate to different other FormPage(s). I did search on that, but no helpful resource available, so please guide me on how to switch between different form pages of SWT FormEditor. Looking forward for your speedy response and thanks.

Comment: Note: Everyone here is volunteering their valuable time. Asking for 'a speedy response' is rude, people will answer when they have time available.

Comment: yes thats true., accepted and my apologies

Answer (score 2):

Note: `FormEditor` and `FormPage` are Eclipse Forms not SWT.

`FormEditor` has several `setActivePage` methods that you can call:

```
public IFormPage setActivePage(String pageId)
```

> Sets the active page using the unique page identifier.

```
public IFormPage setActivePage(String pageId, Object pageInput)
```

> Sets the active page using the unique page identifier and sets its
>   input to the provided object.

```
protected void setActivePage(int pageIndex)
```

> Sets the currently active page.

Comment: Thanks for the response and I am able to use this. But is it possible to call the setActivePage(pageId) from a FormPage.?

Comment: You can call `getEditor()` in the FormPage to get the editor so you can then call that method.

Comment: Thank you so much  greg-449, its working fine. thanks again.